# responsive hamburger navbar not functioning in django base.html

Tags: javascript, python, html, css, django

I am developing simple blogging site, the problem I am facing is my navbar is not responsive, below is my navbar seen in desktop.

[image]

but as I decrease the size of browser, nav bar gets hidden

[image]

what I need is hamburger icon on left top when I decrease the size of the screen on clicking that all navbar menu items should be visible vertically.

[image]

below is my code:

```
{% load static %}

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    {% if title %}
    <title>{{ title }}</title>
    {% else %}
    <title>Young Minds</title>
    {% endif %}
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/bootstrap.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/animate.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/owl.carousel.min.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/fonts/ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/fonts/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/fonts/flaticon/font/flaticon.css' %}">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'blog/css/style.css' %}">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Hind&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Patrick+Hand&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merienda&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Theme Style -->


    <!-- jquery functions -->

  </head>
  <body>




      <header role="banner">




        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-light bg-light">



            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
              <ul class="navbar-nav" style="font-family: 'Hind', sans-serif;margin-left:198px;">
                {% with url_name=request.resolver_match.url_name %}

                <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:15px;margin-left:-20px;">

                  <a class="nav-link active" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}" style="margin-top:-3px;">
                    <span style="font-size: 18px;">Blog </span></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:15px;margin-left:88px;">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown" style="margin-right:15px;">
                  <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="category.html" id="dropdown04" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Catogery</a>
                  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown04">
                    {% for category in categories %}


                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="{% url 'category-posts' category.category__category %}">{{category.category__category}}</a>
                    {% endfor %}
                  </div>

                </li>

                <li class="nav-item dropdown {% if url_name == 'index' %}active{% endif %}" style="margin-right:15px;">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'about' %}">About Us</a>
                </li>
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:15px;">
                  <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'profile' user%}">Profile</a>
                </li>

                  <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:15px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'post-create' %}">Create Blog</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="margin-right:15px;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'user-posts' user %}">My Blogs</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item" style="float: left;">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'logout' %}" >Logout({{ user.username }})</a>
                  </li>
                {% else %}
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'login' %}">Login</a>
                  </li>
                  <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'registration' %}">Signup</a>
                  </li>
                {% endif %}
                {% endwith %}
              </ul>

            </div>
          </div>

      </header>




{% block content%}


{% endblock content%}



<footer class="site-footer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row mb-5">
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <h3>Developer's Message</h3>
        <p class="mb-4">

        </p>

        <p>Wish you all a very good day ! Enjoy Blogging ! <i class="fa fa-smile-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></p>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-6 ml-auto">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-7">
            <h3>Quick Links</h3>
            <ul class="list-unstyled">
              <li >
                <a  href="{% url 'blog-home' %}">Home</a>
              </li>
              <li><a href="{% url 'about' %}">About</a></li>

              <li class="About"><a href="#categories_jquery">Categories</a></li>
            </ul>

          </div>


            <div class="mb-6">
              <h3>Social</h3>
              <ul class="list-unstyled footer-social">
                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span> Twitter</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-facebook"></span> Facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><span class="fa fa-instagram"></span> Instagram</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
        <p class="small">
      <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      Copyright &copy; <script data-cfasync="false" src="/cdn-cgi/scripts/5c5dd728/cloudflare-static/email-decode.min.js"></script><script>document.write(new Date().getFullYear());</script>
      <!-- Link back to Colorlib can't be removed. Template is licensed under CC BY 3.0. -->
      </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
<!-- END footer -->



<!-- loader -->

<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery-migrate-3.0.0.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/popper.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/owl.carousel.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.waypoints.min.js' %}"></script>
<script src="{% static 'blog/js/jquery.stellar.min.js' %}"></script>


<script src="{% static 'blog/js/main.js' %}"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

$('.reply-btn').click(function(){
  console.log($(this).parent());
  console.log($(this).parent().parent());
  console.log($(this).parent().parent().next());

  $(this).parent().parent().next('.comment-body').fadeToggle()
  console.log("trigerred")

});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.About').click(function(event) {
    $("#About-content").toggle("slow");

  });
});

$(document).ready(function(event){
    $(document).on('click',"#like_the_post_by_user", function(event){
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log($("#like_the_post_by_user").val())
      console.log("from jquery section")
      var pk = $(this).attr('value');
      $.ajax({
        type : "POST",
        url : "{% url 'like_post' %}",
        data : {'id': pk , "csrfmiddlewaretoken": '{{ csrf_token }}' },
        dataType : 'json',
        success : function(response){
          $('#like-section_user').html(response['form'])
          console.log($('#like-section_user').html(response['form']));
        },
        error : function(rs, e){
          console.log(rs.responseText);
        }

      });

    });

  });

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried searching everywhere and tested on my own but I couldn't do it myself.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This code says nothing about your actual problem. It's css / js issue. If you are depending on some library to do responsiveness for you, make sure you include all it requires (usually it will be .js files and .css files). If you want to make it on your own, you can implement it either pure css or use some javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a toggle button to have a hamburger menu

in your case would be something like

```html
<header role="banner">
  <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md  navbar-light bg-light">
      <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarMenu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
      </button>
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarMenu">
        ...
      </div>
    </div>
</header>
...
```